# Laravel 5 file and image upload

Tags: php, laravel

View:

```
<input type="file" name="photo">
<button class="btn">Send</button>
<input type="submit" value="send">    //    I tested by input and button but it also does not work
```

Controller:

```
$f = $request->file("photo");
if($f->isValid()){
  echo "upload"
  $f->move("/public/upload/file.png");
}else{
  echo 'not upload';
}
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function isValid() on null
```

I do not know why but I can not do upload images to the site. I've tried many ways but nothing works. Send files by request and get an error, I tried to use a Request::file('photo') or Input::file('photo')->isValid() but it not work too.

```
var_dump($request->file('prod_photo'));
```

If you will use such code in response gets NULL

EDIT:

```
$f = $request->file('photo');
if ($f->isValid()) {
            $ext = $f->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $org_name = $f->getClientOriginalName();
            $r = rand(11111,999999);
$f->move("public/uploads", $r.$org_name);
    //
}
```

How can I change the image size and check if the file is certainly the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form

**EDIT:**

You can easily check it with validator, like so:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'photo' => 'required|image' //works for jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg
]);
```

Unfortunely u cant change image size with native php (as i know), you need to use either  [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [Glide](https://github.com/thephpleague/glide) (which needs previous one)

Comment: How can I change the image size and check if the file is certainly the picture? I changed the question and added the code, you can check it?